# PHP: If statement returns True instead of False

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called as `myArr`. It contains strings and integers, e.g.

```
0  st ts 0  0
st 0  0  0  0
```

For debugging the php script, I'm using Zend Studio. The debug window says that a `cell [0][0]` contains int 0. BUT the problem is that IF statement returns TRUE.

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
          for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
            if ($myArr[$i][$j] == 'ts' || $myArr[$i][$j] == 'st') {
                $num++;
            }
          }
        }
```

UPDATE: I'm running the code in Debug mode in Zend Studio. So, I can see that $num is increasing in each iteration. Also, I can see that cursor goes inside the loop

Comment: How do you know it's returning true, is `$num` equal to 10?

Comment: @rudi_visser: I'm runnign the code in Debug mode. So, I can see that $num is increasing in each iteration. Also, I can see that cursor goes inside the loop.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Debug mode" in the context of the real PHP parser. What is the actual output of PHP when executing directly? Ignore Zend Studio for now.

Comment: @Gusgus: so you can add watch to `$myArr[$i][$j]` expression and see its **actual** value then

Comment: @rudi_visser: there is, using `xdebug`

Comment: Read up on how `==` and `===` work in PHP.

Comment: @zerkms: Watch window shows that the value of $myArr[0][0] is 0

Comment: @zerkms That's not a Debug Mode per se, just a plugin providing the functionality :D But anyway, answered!

Comment: @rudi_visser: it is a debug mode, when you may doing everything debug mode is implying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a string is compared to an integer, the string will be converted to an integer automatically and in your case the string has no digits so it will be evaluated to zero leading to satisfy the equality, you have two options:

`if ('0' == 'tr')`

**OR**

`if (0 === 'tr')`

were the === means check for the value and **type**.
I also found this helpful for you [from the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero)

Answer (score 8):

Because `0 == 'ts'` is `true`. You need to use the equality comparison `===`. Otherwise, PHP's type juggling causes this statement to evaluate to `true`.

See [this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ICEqKZ) to show why the if statement is evaluating to `true`.

Answer (score -2):

any string compared to 0 it's true